# joint PDF of continuous and discrete random variables

Tags: random-variable, density-function, joint-distribution, discrete-distributions

Given exponential a random distribution X with PDF $f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ and a random variable Z with the PMF $p_Z[z]=0.5, z= \pm1$, I am trying to find the PDF of $Y=ZX$ (I also know that Z and X are independent).

The fact that Z is discrete is throwing me off a bit. My guess is that
$$f_{Y}(y)=f_x(y)P[Z=1]+f_x(y)P[Z=-1]=\lambda e^{-\lambda y}$$

or is it just: $f_{Y}(y)=f_X(y)p_Z[y]$?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no joint pdf, contrary to the suggestion in your title.

Comment: Are you suggesting that i find the joint pdf of $f_{X,Y}(x, y)$ and then calculate marginal PDF $f_Y(y)$?

Comment: I am saying a joint pdf doesn't exist, but your title implies it does.

Comment: You could change your title to ask for the *joint distribution*.  There are many similar questions, [see through this list](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=joint+distr*+discre*+and+conti*++answers%3A1)